# Pick overloaded method as argument

Tags: c#

```
namespace PickOverload;

class Program {

    delegate string Formatter( object o );

    string Show( double a ) { return a.ToString(); }

    string Show( int a ) { return a.ToString(); }

    string Format( Formatter f, object o ) { return f( o ); }

    void SelectArgument() {
        // error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Program.Formatter'
        Format( Show, 1.234 );
    }

    void SelectDelegate() {
        // error CS0123: No overload for 'Show' matches delegate 'Program.Formatter
        Formatter x = this.Show;
    }

    void Run() {
        SelectArgument();
        SelectDelegate();
    }

    static void Main( string[] args ) {
        new Program().Run();
    }
}
```

Is there a C# syntax for picking one of the overloaded `Show` methods as argument for the `Format` method or for the delegate?

I'm not looking for a solution for the above sample, but for ways to pick one of multiple overloaded methods for delegates or method arguments.

Same problem here:

```
void Run() { 
  double f = 1.234; 
  Format( Show, f ); 
  Formatter x = this.Show; 
} 

static void Main(string[] args ) { 
  new Program().Run(); 
}
```

Comment: Same problem here:

 void Run() {
  double f = 1.234;
  Format( Show, f );
  Formatter x = this.Show;
 }

 static void Main( string[] args ) {
  new Program().Run();
 }

Comment: Please don't add more information in comments. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with generics, for example:

```
internal delegate string Formatter<T>(T o);

internal static string Show(double a) => a.ToString();
internal static string Show(int a) => a.ToString();

internal static string Format<T>(Formatter<T> f, T o) => f(o);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double f = 1.234;
    Format(Show, f);
}
```

Comment: The Format method in reality is much larger and so I don't want to use generics for it. My question is very specific regarding the selection of overloaded methods. I cannot find valid syntax in C# for doing this. It's more like a general problem: how to get a pointer to an overloaded method in C#.

Comment: Neither `Show` method takes an `object` so you can't cast to your `Formatter(object)` delegate. Generics are the only good solution here.

Comment: Also @cskwg now you're saying its a requirement not to use Generics making this a Chameleon question.

Comment: It's not really a chameleon; from the beginning I was looking for a way to identify overloaded members, i.e. get pointers to overloaded methods. I know, that there are different ways to solve the original problem, like generics or lambdas.